# LINQ - Decide which date is the oldest for each record

Tags: c#, linq

Hey i got a list having many records inside, there are 3 DateTime inside (nullable). What i need is to get a LINQ expression determining which one of this three is the latest then select that record and check again. Here is the code how i created the List.

```
List<ActivityJoinUserTopicVote> ActivityList = new List<ActivityJoinUserTopicVote>();
foreach (var p in postdate)
{
    ActivityList.Add(new ActivityJoinUserTopicVote(p.R_Posted, p.Forum_id, p.R_Posted_By, p.R_Message, p.Reply_ID, p.Topic_ID, p.User));
}
foreach (var v in votedate)
{
    ActivityList.Add(new ActivityJoinUserTopicVote(v.data, v.Topic_ID, v.vote, v.Member_ID, v.Vote_Member_ID));
}
foreach (var t in topicdate)
{
    ActivityList.Add(new ActivityJoinUserTopicVote(t.T_date, t.Forum_id, t.T_Originator, t.T_Replies, t.T_ukaz, t.Topic_ID, t.User, t.T_Url, t.T_subject));
}
return ActivityList;
```

Before returning the ActivityList i need it to determine which one was the most recent and sort it this way. Maybe i could do this somehow while creating the list? The problem is i got 3 different columns inside i need to check in (R_Posted, data and T_date)

Comment: Nah since we got 3 different columns (data, T_date and R_Posted). I tried something like this  ActivityList.OrderBy(d => d.data)
                .ThenBy(d => d.R_Posted)
                .ThenBy(d => d.T_date);
but it dosnt work neither

Comment: Yep I understood now, It is three different variables you want to compare, not the same one. You should clarifiy that in the question. The foreaches seem redundant, they dont add any value to what you are asking for besides actually describing what ActivityJoinUserTopicVote is.

Comment: Yeah thats why i have problem with this, i hardly ever used LINQ and if i did it were only some simple queries.

Comment: What's the relationship between them? and what does `ActivityJoinUserTopicVote` look like?

Comment: Which is the schema of ActivityJoinUserTopicVote because I really don't understand what you are trying doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Get the maximum of 3 dates using ticks, and sort by that value:

**Helper:**

```
private long MaxOfThreeDate(DateTime? date1, DateTime? date2, DateTime? date3)
{
    long max1 = Math.Max(date1.GetValueOrDefault().Ticks, date2.GetValueOrDefault().Ticks);

    return Math.Max(max1, date3.GetValueOrDefault().Ticks);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
return ActivityList.OrderByDescending(x => MaxOfThreeDate(x.data, x.R_Posted, x.T_date)).ToList();
```

Comment: Just writing that answer myself, just wasn't fast enough!

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
return ActivityList;
```

with

```
return ActivityList.OrderByDescending(x =>  x.data.HasValue ? x.data : ( x.R_Posted.HasValue ? x.R_Posted : x.T_date)).ToList();
```

or

```
return ActivityList.OrderByDescending(x => new DateTime?[]{ x.data, x.R_Posted, x.T_date}.Max()).ToList();
```

to return the `ActivityList` sorted by the date fields descending

Answer (score 1):

You can get the most recent one using this

```
var list = ActivityList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).First();
```